# Fire jquery function after Foundation Reveal has opened

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using [Foundation's Reveal](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html) that opens a modal, how can I make the following code fire after the modal has opened?

```
jQuery(document).foundation();

// Ensure all product code cells are the same height
$('.product-codes').each(function(){
  // Cache the highest
  var highestBox = 0;
  // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
  $('.column-data', this).each(function(){
    // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
    if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
      highestBox = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest
  $('.column-data',this).height(highestBox);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your functions on `open.zf.reveal` event

```
jQuery(document).on('open.zf.reveal',function(){

// Ensure all product code cells are the same height
$('.product-codes').each(function(){
  // Cache the highest
  var highestBox = 0;
  // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
  $('.column-data', this).each(function(){
    // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
    if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
      highestBox = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest
  $('.column-data',this).height(highestBox);
});

});
```